# limit number of boosted documents

Tags: solr, solr-boost

We have some use cases where we need a small number of boosted documents at the beginning, but the whole result should not be sorted by the boost query.

Examples:

- add some paid results to the front, but this should be limited, otherwise, if there are many, users see only the advertisements and not the real results.
- promote some users (e.g. in a dating app, show some premium users on top)
- show pretty user on top (e.g. in card view, on top of the deck, there should be a nice user)

At the moment we do this with 2 different queries and put the results together (first x users from the pretty/premium/promoted list and then the rest), but this makes paging very complicated and buggy, because we have 2 different cursorMarks.

So I am looking for a solution to limit the boosted documents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Query Elevation Component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/the-query-elevation-component.html)

> The Query Elevation Component lets you configure the top results for a
>   given query regardless of the normal Lucene scoring.

You can add the QueryElevationComponent to any request handler in the *solrconfig.xml* file. First, define the component :

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
  <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
  <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
  <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
</searchComponent>
```

the component may

- include a `config-file` argument - in this case elevated query results are configured in the linked external XML file (like in the example above, see [`elevate.xml`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/the-query-elevation-component.html#the-elevate-xml-file)).
- otherwise, elevated query results should be passed in at query time using the [`elevateIds` & `excludeIds`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/the-query-elevation-component.html#the-elevateids-and-excludeids-parameters) parameters.

Then add the component to your request handler definition :

```
<requestHandler name="<yourRequestHandler>" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <!-- your base configuration -->
  <!-- ....................... -->
  <arr name="last-components">
    <str>elevator</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, so i try to search for the elevated documents first and add them to the elevateIds, because query is too complex to define in xml.